# how does this code give new id for each thing object. id should be equal to 1 all the time

Tags: java

```
class Thing {
    public static int count = 0;
    public int id = 0;

    public Thing() {
        id = count;
        count++;
    }

    public void ID() {
        System.out.println("This object has id: " + id);
    }
}

public class wth {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thing thing1 = new Thing();
        Thing thing2 = new Thing();
        Thing thing3 = new Thing();

        thing1.ID();
        thing2.ID();
        thing3.ID();
    }
}

Shouldn't this code print 1
                          1
```

Here is what I understand of the code:

First of all, the `thing1` object is created and the constructor Thing runs thus making `id=0` and `count=1`. Then `thing2` is created and again the constructor runs making `id=1` and `count=2`.

Now `thing1.ID()` runs printing the value of id which should be `1` but instead its `0` please explain how is it 0.

Comment: No. `count` is static. It's not associated with an instance but with the class itself

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int count=0;
```

This line means that the variable `count` is linked to the class, not the object. So every time a new `Thing` is created, the incrementation of this variable is applied across all the objects instantiating the class, including new instances that are made.

You can find more info [in the official doc/tutorial here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Answer (score 1):

This code illustrates the way `static` works. `count` is shared among all objects of the class, so it gets incremented each time a new `Thing` object is instantiated.

**Note:** This will break in concurrent environments: if you run this from multiple threads, some objects may get the same `id`. A better implementation would use `AtomicInteger`:

```
class Thing{
    public static AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
    public int id;
    public Thing(){
        id=count.incrementAndGet();
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`count` is static, which is why it gets incremented each time you create a new instance of `Thing` but `id` isn't. That means that each instance of `Thing`, being `thing1`and `thing2` will each have their own id.

Answer (score 0):

**In your question:**

> value of `id` which should be `1` but instead its `0` please explain how is
>   it 0.

What I understood, you asking for first time you create object it's value should be `1` and next time increment by 1. If it is asked for,

**Reason:**

When you create first object(`thing1`) you are calling default constructor(`Thing()`), which you have implemented. And in the first line you assigning `count` variable value to `id` variable which is `0`. Then you increment `count` by one. It is not affecting to id variable first time. Then, you call the `ID()` method, it will print, value that it hold `0`.

**Solution:**

```
public Thing() {
   id = count;
   count++;
}
```

move the `count++;` to first line. Should be:

```
public Thing() {
   count++;
   id = count;
}
```

**Output become:**

```
This object has id: 1
This object has id: 2
This object has id: 3
```

Because of `static` each time you create new object `count` will increment.

**If you want to get outputt as `1` every time:**

> First you want to know about `static` keyword:
>
> - Attributes and methods(member of a class) can be defined as `static`.
> - `static` members do not belongs to an individual object.
> - `static` members are common to all the instances(objects of the same class).
> - `static` members are stores in static memory(a common memory location which can by everybody).

The `static` modifier indicates that the `count` variable(attribute) are common to all the `Thing` in the whole class rather than to an individual object.

To answer your question:

```
public static int count = 0;
```

As I mention above this `count` variable common for all the objects. That means when you create a different objects it's value not changed.

remove the `static` modifier, should be:

```
public int count = 0;
```

When you removed `static` modifier `count` variable become individual for all the objects that you are creating. And for each object it will print as follows:

```
This object has id: 0
This object has id: 0
This object has id: 0
```

If you move the `count++;` to first line.

```
public Thing() {
   count++;
   id = count;
}
```

**Output become:**

```
This object has id: 1
This object has id: 1
This object has id: 1
```